# Toggling with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjdQQ/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="p1">
<a href="javascript:void(0)">p1</a>
<p "style=display:none;">hi</p>
</div>
<div id="p2">
<a href="javascript:void(0)">p1</a>
<p "style=display:none;">welcome</p>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#p1").click(function () {

    $("#p1 p").toggle();
});
$("#p2").click(function () {

    $("#p2 p").toggle();
});
```

In this when i click p1 it is showing its contents and similary p2. What I need is to display only the clicked contents description the other needs to be hide.How can i do this.

Comment: you want this --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/BjdQQ/3/ ?

Comment: I dont want like this

Comment: or this http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/BjdQQ/5/ or http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/BjdQQ/6/ ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For blocks of code with common logic, you should definitely try to genericise your code. With that in mind, use classes instead of ids, and try this:

```
<div id="p1" class="content-toggle">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">p1</a>
    <p style="display:none;">hi</p>
</div>
<div id="p2" class="content-toggle">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">p1</a>
    <p style="display:none;">welcome</p>
</div>
```

```js
$('.content-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.content-toggle p').hide();
    $('p', this).show();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxyrg/)

Note, you also had the `"` in the wrong place on the `style` attribute of your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/bGjsm/)**

```
$("#p1").click(function () {
    $("p").each(function() {
        if ($(this).parent("a").attr("id") !== "p1") {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
    $("#p1 p").toggle();
});
$("#p2").click(function () {
    $("p").each(function() {
        if ($(this).parent("a").attr("id") !== "p2") {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
    $("#p2 p").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below

```
$("#p1").click(function () {
    $("#p2 p").hide();
    $("#p1 p").toggle();
});
$("#p2").click(function () {

    $("#p1 p").hide();
    $("#p2 p").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/BjdQQ/6/)

```
$("#p1").click(function () {
    $('#p2 p').hide();
    $("#p1 p").toggle();
});
$("#p2").click(function () {
    $('#p1 p').hide();
    $("#p2 p").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#p1").click(function () {

    $("#p1 p").css('display','');
    $("#p2 p").css('display','none');
});
$("#p2").click(function () {

    $("#p2 p").css('display','');
    $("#p1 p").css('display','none');
});
```

Here is [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjdQQ/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I may do it like

```
<div class="item"> 
    <a class="header" href="#">p1
        <p style="display:none;">hi</p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item"> 
    <a class="header" href="#">p2
        <p style="display:none;">hi</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

and

```
var $ps = $('.item p')
$(".item a").click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this), $p = $this.children('p');
    $ps.not($p).hide();
    $p.toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TE3Pc/)

Answer (score 1):

You need extra check on click.

```
$("#p1").click(function () {
    $("#p1 p").toggle();
    if ($("#p2 p").is(':visible')) {
        $("#p2 p").toggle();
    }
});
$("#p2").click(function () {
    $("#p2 p").toggle();
    if ($("#p1 p").is(':visible')) {
        $("#p1 p").toggle();
    }
});
```